# $\bigcup_{n}V_n$ is dense in $V$ implies $\bigcup_{n}L^2(0,T;V_n)$ is dense in $L^2(0,T;V)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces

Let $V$ be a separable Hilbert space with basis $w_j$ and let $V_n$ denote the linear span of $w_j$ for $j=1,...,n$. Clearly $V_n$ are Hilbert spaces and $V_n \subset V_{n+1}$ for all $n$.

We have that $\bigcup_{n}V_n$ is dense in $V$.

Does it follow that
$\bigcup_{n}L^2(0,T;V_n)$ is dense in $L^2(0,T;V)$?

I can't prove it; I can't show that my candidate approximating sequence is measurable (which is necessary for it to lie in $L^2(0,T;V_n)$. This came up in a Galerkin method to showing well-posedness of a particular PDE so I will tag it as pde.

Comment: Think about a different approximating sequence if this one is too cumbersome. For example, Specifically, let $\varphi_n$ be an orthonormal basis of $L^2(0,T;\mathbb{R})$. Now consider the span of all $\varphi_j(\cdot)w_k$, where $j, \, k \le n$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I haven'tsolved it. so the span with $j, k \leq n$ is a subset of $L^2(0,T;V_n)$. Am I supposed to approximate $v \in L^2(0,T;V)$ by a function of the form $\sum_i v_i\phi_i$ where the $v_i \in V$ and $\phi_t \in C_c^\infty(0,T).$ Is this what you were intending?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basis $w_j$ can be taken to be orthonormal without loss of generality.

I use $\|\cdot\|$ below to mean the norm on $V$.

The idea is to create an approximating function $f_n$ by projecting $f(t)$ onto $V_n$.

Suppose $f:[0,T] \to V$ satisfies $\int \|f(t)\|^2 d \mu(t)< \infty$. Then define $f_n: [0,T] \to V_n$ by $f_n(t) = \sum_{k=1}^n \langle w_k, f(t) \rangle w_k$.

Then $\|f_n(t)\|^2  = \sum_{k=1}^n | \langle w_k, f(t) \rangle |^2 \le \|f(t)\|^2$ by Bessel's inequality, and since $\ w_j$ is a basis, we have $f_n(t) \to f(t)$ for all $t$. Hence we have $\int \|f_n(t)\|^2 d \mu(t) \le \int \|f(t) \|^2 d \mu(t)$, and since $\|f(t)-f_n(t)\| \le 2\|f(t)\|$, the dominated convergence theorem gives
$\int \|f(t)-f_n(t)\|^2 d \mu(t)\to 0$.

Hence $f_n \to f$.

Comment: Nice answer. If $w_j$ were not orthogonal, would the approximating functions look like $f_n(t) = \sum_k a_k(t)w_k$? Do we know anything nice about the coefficients?

Comment: Well, if the $w_j$ were not orthogonal, you could use Gram Schmidt to orthogonalize them to, say, $\hat{w}_j$. Since $\operatorname{sp} \{ w_j \} = \operatorname{sp} \{ \hat{w_j} \} $, we can write the approximating functions in the manner you wrote.